# Get file extension by its name

Tags: c#, combobox, io, delete-file

I want to delete a file with its name and the containing folder;
when I say name I mean without the extension.

Here is the way I know. (with a little help of you, it will works)

```
//the  extension string doesn't work properly.Here I need your help
string extension = Path.GetExtension(@"C:\Projects_2012\Project_Noam\Files\ProteinPic" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
string fileLoc = @"C:\Projects_2012\Project_Noam\Files\ProteinPic\" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + extension;
if (File.Exists(fileLoc))
{
    File.Delete(fileLoc);
}
```

Comment: What when the are multiple files with the same name and different extensions?

Comment: @Radu, why didn't you edit the formatting for the good of SO users?

Comment: @TimSchmelter i don't give it to be files with the same name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2) and use an `*` in place of the extension.

Answer (score 0):

As an exact translation of your code, this is what I would write:

```
string extension = @".txt"; // For example;
string basePath = "@C:\SomePath\";
string pathWithoutExtension = Path.GetExtension(Path.Combine(basePath, comboBox1.Text));
string fullPath = Path.ChangeExtension(pathWithourExtension, extension);

if (!File.Exists(fullPath))
    // Do stuff...
else
    // Do other stuff...
```

Done.

Comment: but it is not an txt file. it is png/jpeg/jpg/gif file